# How to make text aligin in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.Net, how to apply text align [left,center,right] in a column, when autogenerate column is true. In every row of gridview the text is displayed in center of the column, i want to display in left side of the column. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using below syntax if all the columns needs to left aligned

```
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></RowStyle>
```

Also check these [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) resource which has various examples for GridView formatting and [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/FrmtAutoGenClmnASPNETGrid.aspx) article which shows examples for `AutoGenerated` Columns scenerio.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, this case will work only when `autogeneratedcolumns = "false"`. See the edit for the `autogeneratecolumns="true"` If you want to align the header of the column add this to the BoundFiled:

```
 HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
```

And if you want to align the item of the column add this to the BoundField:

```
 ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
```

EDIT:

Also try this too
Click on the gridView->properties->RowStyle:horizontal-align

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource"
```

---

```
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
```

---

```
    allowpaging="true"
    ondatabound="CustomersGridView_DataBound"  
    runat="server">

    <pagerstyle forecolor="Blue"
      backcolor="LightBlue"/>

    <pagertemplate>

      <table width="100%">                    
        <tr>                        
          <td style="width:70%">

            <asp:label id="MessageLabel"
              forecolor="Blue"
              text="Select a page:" 
              runat="server"/>
            <asp:dropdownlist id="PageDropDownList"
              autopostback="true"
              onselectedindexchanged="PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              runat="server"/>

          </td>
```

---

```
          <td style="width:70%; text-align:right">
```

---

```
            <asp:label id="CurrentPageLabel"
              forecolor="Blue"
              runat="server"/>

          </td>

        </tr>                    
      </table>

    </pagertemplate> 

  </asp:gridview>
```

more info on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.horizontalalign.aspx)

Comment: `Autogenerated` columns means no `<Columns>` tags, so `<ItemStyle>` would not even come into view.

Comment: @HarshBaid, now i have edited my post. Thanks for your alerting.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `<RowStyle>` and `<HeaderStyle>` elements in your markup.

Example:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="productGridView" Runat="server" 
      DataSourceID="productsDataSource"
        DataKeyNames="ProductID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
         CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
         BorderColor="#DEBA84">
        <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
          BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
          HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
          BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I think `Autogenerated` columns means no `<Columns>` tags, so `<ItemStyle>` would not even come into view.

Comment: My gridview is autogeneratecolumn="true"

Comment: @HarshBaid Wrong, they can, of course. You can set style for Rows, alternating rows, header, footer, pager, etc. See here and notice how the `<columns>` section is independent of the different styles defined. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Comment: @HarshBaid I think you meant it to say because I mentioned ItemStyle instead of RowStyle. I was thinking of DataGrid instead of GridView. I corrected to the appropriate term but the idea is the same anyway.

Comment: yes but only when we have `<Columns>` defined then we can use `ItemStyle`, mostly when `AutoGenerated` option is used then columns are skipped in Syntax..

Answer (score 1):

Put your columns as template fields as per below and give **ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"**

```
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="No." ItemStyle- 
     HorizontalAlign="Left">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

So it will work in all browser.